# how to add a new modulo position on a joomla template?

Tags: templates, joomla, module, add-in, position

i'm using a joomla template called decayed and it doesn't have the right position, only the left one and nothing more.

i would like to add a right and a button positions on that template. how can i do it?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using joomla 1.5, go into the template directory (/templates/someTemplateName/). I don't know anything about this theme, but if it follows the standard scheme for a joomla template, then modify these two files:

1) index.php

```
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="myModulePosition" />
```

Add that wherever you want your module to appear in the template (and substitute "myModulePosition" for what ever you want the module position to be named).

2) templateDetails.xml

Find the xml tag , should probably look something like this:

```
    <positions>
        <position>left</position>
    </positions>
```

And add a new tag with your new position, such as:

```
    <positions>
        <position>left</position>
        <position>myModulePosition</position>
    </positions>
```

That way, your module position will show up in the list of available positions when you're adding/modifying modules.

Comment: thanx for the quick answer,
i did it but it how the new module position at botton of the left position.

something like that:

[left]
[myModulePosition]

:(

the template is called ND_Decayed: http://www.nukedesign.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

scott solution may not work at all.

I simply do this by going to DB find module in **#__modules** table and add in the field **"position"** the name of desired position, It is hard way but it work's well